# Kill Command in linux using bash script

Tags: linux, bash, kill, command, sleep

I have a **bash** script **abcd.sh**,in which I want to kill this command`(/usr/local/bin/wrun 'uptime;ps -elf|grep httpd|wc -l;free -m;mpstat')` after 5 sec but in this script it kill `sleep` command after 5 second.

```
#!/bin/sh
/usr/local/bin/wrun 'uptime;ps -elf|grep httpd|wc -l;free -m;mpstat' &
sleep 5
kill $! 2>/dev/null && echo "Killed command on time out"
```